# How to use module manuf in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use module manuf in python for manufacturer/lookup mac address but why isn't working?

Code :

```
import sys 
from datetime import datetime

try:
        interface = input("[*] Enter Desired Interface: ")
        ips = input("[*] Enter Range of IPs to Scan for: ")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("\n[*] User Requested Shutdown") 
        print ("[*] Quitting...")
        sys.exit(1)
print ("\n[*] Scanning... ") 
start_time = datetime.now() 

from scapy.all import srp,Ether,ARP,conf 
import manuf

conf.verb = 0 
ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst = ips), timeout = 2, iface=interface,inter=0.1)

print ("Hasil : \n") 
rcv = manuf.manuf.MacParser()
for snd,rcv in ans:
    print (rcv.sprintf(r"%Ether.src% - %ARP.psrc%",rcv.get_all(r"%Ether.src% - %ARP.psrc%"))) 
stop_time = datetime.now() 
total_time = stop_time - start_time 
print ("\n[*] Scan Complete!") 
print ("[*] Scan Duration: %s" %(total_time))
```

Output :

```
[s1gnific4nt@s1gnific4nt-pc KKP]$ sudo python filter.py

[*] Enter Desired Interface: wlp3s0
[*] Enter Range of IPs to Scan for: 192.168.3.0/24

[*] Scanning...
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?). This affects only IPv6
Hasil :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filter.py", line 21, in <module>
    rcv = manuf.manuf.MacParser()
AttributeError: module 'manuf' has no attribute 'manuf'
```

i'm following this because i using pip version but still not working : https://github.com/coolbho3k/manuf/issues/8

I try to changed `rcv = manuf.manuf.MacParser()` to `rcv = manuf.MacParser()` and still not working

Output after changed :

```
 [s1gnific4nt@s1gnific4nt-pc KKP]$ sudo python filter.py

[*] Enter Desired Interface: wlp3s0
[*] Enter Range of IPs to Scan for: 192.168.3.0/24

[*] Scanning...
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?). This affects only IPv6
Hasil :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filter.py", line 21, in <module>
    rcv = manuf.MacParser()
AttributeError: module 'manuf' has no attribute 'MacParser'
```

My Python version : 3.6.4

Comment: So change `manuf.manuf.MacParser()` to `manuf.MacParser()`?

Comment: I'm trying too, but still error like this : 'Error' message: 'E1101:Module 'manuf' has no 'MacParser' member' at: '21,7'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import manuf.manuf
```

then you can do

```
manuf.manuf.MacParser(...)
```

Comment: that give me output error like this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/manuf/manuf.py", line 67, in __init__
    self.refresh()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/manuf/manuf.py", line 82, in refresh
    with io.open(manuf_name, "r", encoding="utf-8") as read_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'manuf'

Comment: That's an error specific to the `manuf` package but it would appear that your import error is solved. It looks like if you don't pass a `manuf_name` to `MacParser` by default it uses `manuf`. Probably best to read the source. Its only ~300 lines. If you are still having trouble I would ask a separate question.

Comment: `manuf_name (str): Location of the manuf data base file. Defaults to "manuf" in the same directory.` <-- From the docstring. Make sure you have the manuf database file in the same directory as the python file you are running. Then pass the name of that file to `MacParser(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the error message?

> AttributeError: module 'manuf' has no attribute 'manuf'

Did you check your code?

```
rcv = manuf.manuf.MacParser()
```

Did you try

```
rcv = manuf.MacParser()
```

instead?

Comment: sure, but if i changed, result of output still error like this : 'Error' message: 'E1101:Module 'manuf' has no 'MacParser' member' at: '21,7'

Comment: Maybe your version of manuf is outdated? For me ``p = manuf.MacParser()`` works fine.